# using fileIO in windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I am trying to use fileIO in my windows VC++2008 (this is what I have set up for everything I need to do) program, and I have done the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
....
ostream Output;
```

intelisense is working fine, and even gives me the methods for the object, but my compiler throws that it does not recognize ostream even though I know that it resides in the fstream header file that is included.

is there something wrong with my compiler, and how do I check?

additional info

I have done the following, and it now recognizes the stream, but I now get a different error

```
std::ofstream Output // instead of ostream Output
Output.open("Output/log.txt", ios::out); //so that I can open the file and specify output as ofstream can go both ways.
```

when I tried to do this as one line with just a constructor I got this issue"

```
1>c:...\engine\gsp420maincore\gsp420maincore\messagequeue.cpp(141) : error C2664: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ostream(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [15]' to 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

when I use the current method my compiler states that

```
error C2653: 'ios' : is not a class or namespace name
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error from the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ofstream` if you're trying to output to a file:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream o("file.txt");
o << "Hello File!";
o.close();
```

The `std::` is needed if you're not `using` the std namespace.

Comment: that's just it I am using the std namespace, and it still throws these errors.]

Comment: Try removing the using statement and adding std:: prefix.

Comment: your suggestion corrected a few problems. please read additional info

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried std::ostream? You might not have included the namespace?

Comment: this is a sub file (to be compiled in between other files), and isn't including a namespace between other compilations a potential killer

Comment: if you're worried about that, you can just prefix ostream with std::. That is safe across modules. std::ostream Output;